# Vimeo iFrame only loads occasionally

Tags: iframe, vimeo, vimeo-player, video-embedding

This vimeo video [loads fine on its own](http://jsfiddle.net/9qPZv/) with the iframe snippet below

```
<iframe src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/19513284?byline=0&amp;portrait=0&amp;color=ffffff" width="350" height="192" frameborder="0" webkitAllowFullScreen mozallowfullscreen allowFullScreen></iframe>
```

But once loaded as part of [this page](https://agapematchdb.com/index.php), it will only work some of the time. I disabled all applicable CSS rules to that iFrame element, but it still won't load.

This happens on Chrome, Firefox and Safari, cleared cache or not.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's because your site is secure. Browsers have started blocking insecure elements loaded on secure pages. The easiest solution is to remove the "http:" from the src of the iframe:

```
<iframe src="//player.vimeo.com/video/19513284?byline=0&amp;portrait=0&amp;color=ffffff" width="350" height="192" frameborder="0" webkitAllowFullScreen mozallowfullscreen allowFullScreen></iframe>
```

That will load via the proper protocol where necessary. Note that we are still working on getting our video files loading over https, but the embed will still work in the meantime (you'll just see a warning in the address bar in some browsers).

Answer (score 1):

Your iFrame source needs to be https://